# Why addOnScrollListener that not work?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try to implement load more when scroll to bottom of recyclerView
It's work when my XML only have recyclerView but when i put it to scrollview and setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) it doesn't work

[image: XML]
" Requirement "
- The orange area is static layout 
- The green area is dynamic items
and when i scoll to bottom orange area must be scroll down too

```
    mAdapter = new RecyclerViewCommentAdapter(commentList, userInformationList);
    mRecyclerViewComment = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewComment);
    mRecyclerViewComment.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mRecyclerViewComment.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerViewComment.setItemViewCacheSize(30);
    mRecyclerViewComment.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mRecyclerViewComment.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    mRecyclerViewComment.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerViewComment.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerViewComment.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Scroll //
    mRecyclerViewComment.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "dy = " + dy);
            if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
            {
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "totalItemCount = " + totalItemCount);
                if (loading)
                {

                    if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount && (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= TOTAL_FIRST_LOAD)
                    {
                        loading = false;
                        loadMoreKey();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I try to debug 'dy' it's always 0

Comment: Can you share the requirement to put a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView?

Comment: Thanks @basilisk Checkout my edited answer

Comment: From the designs, it seems you do not need the scroll view. If you want the orange area to scroll with the list, then add it as another item in RecyclerView (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/493321 ). If you want to to be static and not scroll at all, put both the views in a LinearLayout. In most cases, nested scrolling is not a good idea.

Comment: @basilisk Solved Thanks a lot XD

Answer (score 1):

dy is 0 because `RecyclerView` is not scrolling, its fitting its content in the scroll view. So, the view which is scrolling is `ScrollView`.

This is not a particularly good implementation as all the views in `RecyclerView` are inflated at the same time which beats the purpose of `RecyclerView` which is to reuse the `ViewHolders` when user scrolls and dynamically inflate elements in the View to save memory usage.

Try fixing the height of the `RecyclerView` and don't use `wrap_content` or `match_parent` in the `height` property of your `RecyclerView`

Comment: Thanks for answered, So how should i implement another layout scrolling with recyclerView