# LinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() returns false position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using the following method to implement **lazy loading** for **pagination** in `RecyclerView`:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition(); // starts with 0

            if (!mIsLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                    mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                }

                mIsLoading = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

It works fine on **API levels > 22**. However, on APIs 22 and below, the `onScrolled()` is called multiple times by itself until all the pages are loaded. This eventually causes the app to crash with following error:

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{52d05fac position=6 id=-1, oldPos=5, pLpos:5 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{52820a2c VFED.... .F....ID 0,213-656,3401 #7f0a0122 app:id/
 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5610)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5792)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3763)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3219)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1217)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:321)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:809)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
        at andro
```

On the other hand, When I add the dy>0 condition , `onScrolled()` is called only once:

```
if (!mIsLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold) && dy>0) {
            .
            .
            .
}
```

I would very much appreciate if anyone having faced such a problem or having a solution could share their opinions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

I was using **RecyclerView inside a ScrollView** in my xml layout. I think the ScrollView scrolling action listener has precendece over RecyclerView's in API<=22. Anyways, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44719965/4726718) answer very helpful.

**Note:** If you give RecyclerView a fixed height it will work inside ScrollView too.